# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str postgres/python

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to get a timestamp from a row called time in my postgres database, however I'm getting the error. It's the second row in the database.

The error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` is on the `stamp = cursor.fetchone()["time"]` line.

I would like the tuple to be read as as string in my discord bot. Here is what I'm dealing with:

```
for member in guild.members:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT time FROM blacklist WHERE username=%s", (member.id, ))
        stamp = cursor.fetchone()["time"]
        for time in stamp: 
            if time is not None:
                timestamp = time
                members = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Members")
                restricted_role = get(guild.roles, name="Restricted")
                datestamp = datetime.now()
                datetimestring = str(datestamp.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
                dateonlystring = timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        
                if (datetimestring > dateonlystring):
                    await member.add_roles(members)
                    await member.remove_roles(restricted_role)
                    print("Done.")
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use [asyncpg](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpg/) in async use cases such as discord.py

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code snippet. The one that throws this error is that `cursor.fetchone()` returns a `tuple`, not at `dict` as the error suggests. You need to give it the integer index that correspond to the column named "time" in your return definition, this should be 0.

So you need to change the line:

```
stamp = cursor.fetchone()["time"]
```

to

```
stamp = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

See details at the [psychopg.fetchone()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone)

However, I noticed that `stamp` should be indexed, so that will fail even if you test for `None`.

I made other suggestions in the revised code, based on what it does presumably.

```
for member in guild.members:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Changed the query so that NULLs (which will be cast as None) are not returned
        cursor.execute("SELECT time FROM blacklist WHERE username=%s AND time IS NOT NULL", (member.id, ))

        # no index needed, multiple stamps are returned 
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        for result in results:
            # first and only returned element
            timestamp = result[0] 

            members = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Members")
            restricted_role = get(guild.roles, name="Restricted")
            datestamp = datetime.now()

            datetimestring = str(datestamp.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
            dateonlystring = timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        
            if (datetimestring > dateonlystring):
                    await member.add_roles(members)
                    await member.remove_roles(restricted_role)
                    print("Done.")
```

Comment: Thank you but that has returned `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
`?

Comment: Then your query is not returning anything and you a NULL/None result.