# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime' issue on postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to get a timestamp which is string stored in the time column on my postgres database table. However when trying to get this in my code it is returning the error

`dateonlystring = stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%w-%W %H:%M:%S") AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

I'm not sure why or how to covert the tuple to a string.

My code:

```
async def check_mute(self):
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(750744359650109661)
    for member in list(guild.members):
        member_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Members")
        restricted_role = get(guild.roles, name="Restrict")
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT time FROM blacklist WHERE username=%s", (member.id, ))
        stamp = cursor.fetchall()[0]
        if restricted_role in member.roles:
            if stamp:
                datestamp = datetime.now()
                datetimestring = str(datestamp.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%w-%W %H:%M:%S"))
                dateonlystring = stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%w-%W %H:%M:%S")
                if (datetimestring > dateonlystring):
                    await member.add_roles(member_role)
                    await member.remove_roles(restricted_role)
                    print("Done.")
```

my table setup:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEXAh.png)

Help or some direction on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns an iterable of tuples, ie a list/tuple of tuples. Each outer iterable being a row in the DB, and each element in an inner tuple being a value of a column.

```py
stamp = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

`stamp` is a tuple (as the error suggests). To get the value of the `time` column you need to access `stamp[0]`, so

```
stamp[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%w-%W %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: This gives me `stamp = cursor.fetchall()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
` does that mean it's telling me that it's returning a None? which is strange because the time column does exist.

Comment: @Jasme it means `stamp` is an empty tuple, which means the `where` clause does not return anything. Try to `print(stamp)`

Comment: Some of my time column entries are NULL which might be the reason why it's not returning a stamp. I've edited my question and added a screenshot that shows how my table columns are set out.

Comment: That was explained in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179759/typeerror-tuple-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str-postgres-python) about this. You have to account for the possibility that a value is None.